# iOS library for signing in with Twitter

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm working on an app at the moment that requires the user to be able to sign in or create an account using their twitter credentials.

The user's email address and other personal info should be sent to our client's server.

Does the iOS twitter framework provide access to the user's Twitter user info (name and email) or is this something I'll have to develop myself?

If so, can anyone recommend a 3rd party library that would help me achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of [libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#objectivec) you can leverage to get a users Twitter details. You will not be able to get their email address as Twitter does not provide access through the API and names are freeform and could be first, last, or nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the capabilities of it but theres a 3rd party library called Sharekit which supports twitter, facebook and some other sites I think. It's like a wrapper for all the APIs but I'm not sure what the benefit of using it is if you only plan to use twitter.

Other than that ofc you can retrieve the user info using their framework, It's just a matter lf how simple it is, It's probably done with a HTTP Request to their API, like Facebook does it with Graph API.